# Header paragraph, alignment and column sizing in longtable

Tags: siunitx

How can I add a heading paragraph below the title and before the toprule on the table below? When I use \multicolumn and add a paragraph, it doesn't seem to work. I used \table and \tabular before and could put the paragraph before the \tabular command, but I now need to use a longtable as I'm aligning decimals with siunitx, so I can't put the table in a box.

How can I fit the table into the page width below and specify column widths to improve the layout? I would like to equally space out the AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD columns, but have a space between the four groups to make it easier to read.

When I use the \footnotesize macro, it affects the title and the paragraph of text also, does it? Also, the size of the text in the last paragraph seems to be reduced due to the \footnotesize macro.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

%tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx} %align numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = -1.2}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\lipsum[1]
\footnotesize{
\begin{longtable}{
l 
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3] @{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]}

\caption[Table title]{Table title} \label{treeSummary} \\
    \multicolumn{13}{s}{\lipsum[1]}  \\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{First Group}                                 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Second Group} \\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{AB}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CD} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{EF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GH}\\
\midrule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD}      \\
One         &    2.72  &     1.11  &     0.163 &     1.03  &     1.70   &    0.087 &     0.18  &     0.11  &     {$<$}0.001     &    0.47  &     1.14  &     0.063 \\
Two         &    1.65  &     2.62  &     0.084 &     1.37  &     1.38  &     0.095 &     0.11  &     0.14  &     0.124 &     0.54  &     0.58  &     0.174 \\
Three           &    2.39  &     1.57  &     0.331 &     1.77  &     1.95  &     0.007 &     0.83  &     0.24  &     {$<$}0.001     &    1.18  &     1.07  &     0.004 \\
Four        &    1.05  &     {--}   &       {--}   &     2.72  &     2.99  &     0.144 &     0.07  &     {--}   &    {--}      &     1.67  &     1.40   &   {$<$}0.009 \\
\noalign{\vskip 5pt}   
Sum     &    0.660 &     0.004 &           &     {$<$}0.001 &    0.245 &           &     {$<$}0.001 &    {$<$}0.001 &          &    {$<$}0.001 &     0.010 &        \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the table is short, why `longtable`?

Comment: I need to use it so I can use \usepackage{siunitx} to align decimals. There's a few issues with it that I haven't resolved yet i.e. no \vspace allowed in the table.

Comment: `siunitx` can be used without `longtable` too. At present your table is too wide and using `longtable` will impose restrictions to resize it.

Comment: What do I need to edit in the example above to move it to a regular table environment? If I just change the code from longtable to table, there are errors. Is there a way to specify individual column widths using an alternative table environment?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are going for. The tabular material is still too wide. You could use `\scriptsize` or simply rotate the whole table to landscape.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

%tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx} %align numbers by decimal point
\sisetup{table-format = -1.2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
%this length is now bounded to this
%(and only this) table. If you want to change it globally, put it
%in your preamble
%   \footnotesize
    \scriptsize
\caption[Wombat title]{Wombat title} \label{treeSummary}
\lipsum[1]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{
l 
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3] @{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{First Group}                                 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Second Group} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-7}
\cmidrule(lr){8-13}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{AB}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CD} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{EF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GH}\\
\midrule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD}      \\
One  & 2.72 &  1.11 &  0.163 &  1.03 &  1.70 & 0.087 &  0.18 &  0.11 &  {$<$}0.001  & 0.47 &  1.14 &  0.063 \\
Two  & 1.65 &  2.62 &  0.084 &  1.37 &  1.38 &  0.095 &  0.11 &  0.14 &  0.124 &  0.54 &  0.58 &  0.174 \\
Three   & 2.39 &  1.57 &  0.331 &  1.77 &  1.95 &  0.007 &  0.83 &  0.24 &  {$<$}0.001  & 1.18 &  1.07 &  0.004 \\
Four  & 1.05 &  {--} &  {--} &  2.72 &  2.99 &  0.144 &  0.07 &  {--} & {--} &  1.67 &  1.40 & {$<$}0.009 \\
\noalign{\vskip 5pt} 
Sum  & 0.660 &  0.004 &   &  {$<$}0.001 & 0.245 &   &  {$<$}0.001 & {$<$}0.001 &  & {$<$}0.001 &  0.010 &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This is a screenshot using `\scriptsize` for the tabular and the describing material:

[image]

Comment: Great stuff. If it's now back in the table/tabular environment, can I just put it in a scalebox to reduce the size, or will that affect the rendering of the characters?

Comment: You can scale it, but scaling *always* affects the rendering. Think about a text in footnotesize, if you scale it up so you can see it from 3 meters apart, it will just look ugly. But it is your decision.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `{\footnotesize...` not `\footnotesize{...`. You can use

```
\multicolumn{13}{@{}c@{}}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}}
```

for the intended row. Further, the `S` column will work with other `tabular`s also. Hence if your table is short, better avoid `longtable` so that you can resize it.

Here is an attempt with centred table:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

%tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx} %align numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = -1.2}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption[Table title]{Table title} \label{treeSummary}
\makebox[0pt]{\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3] @{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}
S[table-format = <1.3]@{}}

    \multicolumn{13}{@{}c@{}}{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}\\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{First Group}                                 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Second Group} \\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{AB}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CD} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{EF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GH}\\
\midrule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD}      \\

One         &    2.72  &     1.11  &     0.163 &     1.03  &     1.70   &    0.087 &     0.18  &     0.11  &     {$<$}0.001     &    0.47  &     1.14  &     0.063 \\
Two         &    1.65  &     2.62  &     0.084 &     1.37  &     1.38  &     0.095 &     0.11  &     0.14  &     0.124 &     0.54  &     0.58  &     0.174 \\
Three           &    2.39  &     1.57  &     0.331 &     1.77  &     1.95  &     0.007 &     0.83  &     0.24  &     {$<$}0.001     &    1.18  &     1.07  &     0.004 \\
Four        &    1.05  &     {--}   &       {--}   &     2.72  &     2.99  &     0.144 &     0.07  &     {--}   &    {--}      &     1.67  &     1.40   &   {$<$}0.009 \\
\noalign{\vskip 5pt}
Sum     &    0.660 &     0.004 &           &     {$<$}0.001 &    0.245 &           &     {$<$}0.001 &    {$<$}0.001 &          &    {$<$}0.001 &     0.010 &        \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And a resized table:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{article}

%tables
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx} %align numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}   %% provides \resizebox macro
\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-format = -1.2}

%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
\caption[Table title]{Table title} \label{treeSummary} 
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{%
l
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3] @{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]@{\hskip 0.2cm}
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]
S[table-format = <1.3]}

\multicolumn{13}{@{}c@{}}{%
\begin{minipage}{1.5\linewidth}
\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}}\\
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{First Group}                                 & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Second Group} \\
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{AB}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CD} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{EF} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{GH}\\
\midrule
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{AAA}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{BBB} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CCC} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{DDD}      \\

One         &    2.72  &     1.11  &     0.163 &     1.03  &     1.70   &    0.087 &     0.18  &     0.11  &     {$<$}0.001     &    0.47  &     1.14  &     0.063 \\
Two         &    1.65  &     2.62  &     0.084 &     1.37  &     1.38  &     0.095 &     0.11  &     0.14  &     0.124 &     0.54  &     0.58  &     0.174 \\
Three           &    2.39  &     1.57  &     0.331 &     1.77  &     1.95  &     0.007 &     0.83  &     0.24  &     {$<$}0.001     &    1.18  &     1.07  &     0.004 \\
Four        &    1.05  &     {--}   &       {--}   &     2.72  &     2.99  &     0.144 &     0.07  &     {--}   &    {--}      &     1.67  &     1.40   &   {$<$}0.009 \\
\noalign{\vskip 5pt}
Sum     &    0.660 &     0.004 &           &     {$<$}0.001 &    0.245 &           &     {$<$}0.001 &    {$<$}0.001 &          &    {$<$}0.001 &     0.010 &        \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't recommend to place the lipsum paragraph (or whatever) inside a multicolumn and into the tabular if it doesn't belong there. Look at the vertical spacing, it is very small (text to caption, and text to toprule).

Comment: It is the same font size, if put *in* the table environment.

Comment: My apologies, i wasn't aware of your resizing. But i still think, that resizing something isn't a good idea in most cases.